# Jetty HttpClient ExecutionException vs InterruptedException

Tags: java, network-programming, jetty-9

I'm using jetty to make get requests to a server and retry if they fail,
but I have some questions regarding the exception handling and how to interpret them.

The code looks like below

```
public void run() {
    final int MAX_CONNECTION_WAIT_TIME = 90;
    final long requestTimeOut = 2L;
    long sleep = 1L;
    do {
        final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        try {
            httpClient.start();
            final String resp = httpClient
                .newRequest(socket)
                .timeout(requestTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .send().getContentAsString();
             //do something with the resp
            } catch (TimeoutException toe) {
                //what it means?
            } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                //what it means?
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                httpClient.stop();
            }
            //wait until the next time
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    } while (sleep < MAX_CONNECTION_WAIT_TIME);
}
```

If the request fails (there could be intermittent network issues) I want to retry but just a few times, not forever.

If the above condition happens

- Which exception will happen first?
- Does the TimeoutException imply an ExecutionException?
- if the request fails will the ExecutionException be thrown or the TimeoutException?

The documentation says

```
InterruptedException – if send thread is interrupted
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException – if send times out
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException – if execution fails
```

Right now what I do is to ignore the TimeoutException and catch the ExecutionException and it behaves well, is that the correct way or I'm missing something?

Comment: A `TimeoutException` means the connection [timed out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeout_(computing)). An `ExecutionException` means an error occurred with the connection and will wrap the actual cause (e.g. `ee.getCause()`). And `InterruptedException` means someone interrupted the calling `Thread` which typically implies an attempt to cancel execution.

Comment: Does it mean that whenever a request fail the ExecutionException will always be thrown? and thus that the TimeoutException could be a symptom?

Comment: I can't answer for sure as I'm not familiar with Jetty, but based on the API I don't see why they would do that. There'd be no reason to declare both `throws TimeoutException` and `throws ExecutionException` if the former is never thrown and will always be the cause of the latter. Besides the two exceptions mean different things. This design looks very similar to `Future#get(long,TimeUnit)`.